# css not working on ajax combobox

Tags: asp.net, css, ajax, combobox

Earlier combobox was working correctly. But after applying css to web page combobox itemlist is droping at some other place on page. It happen exactly applying css to page. Image of web page is shown below:

[image]

i have used following css.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
<style type="text/css">
    body {
        font-size: .813em;
        max-width: 1244px;
        padding-left: 12px;
        padding-right: 12px;
        margin: 0;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        font: .875em/1.35 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        background-color:white;
        color: #2a2a2a;   
        line-height: 1.538;    
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
    }

    #Container {
        /*max-width:90%;*/
        clear:right;
        margin-right:auto;
        margin-left:auto;  
        min-width: inherit;
        position: relative;   
        width:inherit; 
    }

    #ux-header {
        padding: 20px 0 0;
        clear: right;
        font-size: .813em;
        line-height: 1.538;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        color: #959595;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 9998;
        background-color:#eee;
    }

        #ux-header .BrandLogo {
            margin: 0;
            float: left;
            height: 40px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        #ux-header .GlobalBar {
            margin: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: 330px;
            width: auto;
            float: right;
            line-height: 1.25;
            font-size: 12px;
        }

        #ux-header .internav {
            padding: 5px 0 12px;
            margin: 0;
            line-height: 1.75;
            font: 14px 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
            border-bottom: solid 1px #ccc;
            clear: both;
        }

    div#body {
        padding-top: 35px;
        clear: both;
        min-width:inherit;
        max-height:100%;
        width:auto;
    }

    div#form {
        margin: 0;
        position:relative;    
        max-width:initial;
       width:auto;       
    }

    div#leftNav {
        width: auto;
        margin: 0 -1px 0 0;
        border-right: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
    }

        div#leftNav.leftNavResize1 {
          width:750px;
        }
    div#Content1.leftform {    
        float:left;
        margin:10px 0px 10px 20px;

    }
    div#Content2.rightImage {
        float:left;
        margin:10px 60px 10px 0px;
        width:auto;    
        text-align:center;
    }

    div#form {
        width:60%;
        float:left;
    }

    div#content {
        border-left: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
        padding-left: 20px;
        margin: 0;
        overflow-x: auto!important;
        min-height: 300px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        width:auto;    
    }

    .topic .title {
        font-family: Segoe UI,Verdana,Arial;
    }

    h1, h1.heading {
        font-size: 3em;
        color: #707070;
    }

    h1 {
        color: #707070;
        font: 100 2.571em/1.167 'Segoe UI Light','Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        margin-top: 0;
        display: block;
        font-size: 2em;
        /*-webkit-margin-before: 0.67em;*/
        -webkit-margin-after: 0.67em;
        -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
        -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
        /*font-weight: bold;*/
    }


    input[type="text"] {
         border-radius: 5px;
         border: 1px solid #999;
         font-family: 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
         width:197px;
         padding:3px;
         border-spacing:3px;
         margin-left:0px;
         margin-right:auto;
    }

        input[type="text"]:focus {
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
            border: 1px solid #5AB0DB;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-family:inherit;
        }

        input[type="text"]:hover {
            border: 1px solid #999;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
            font-family:inherit;
        }

        input[type="text"]:focus:hover {
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
            border: 1px solid #5AB0DB;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-family:inherit;
        }

    select {
         border-radius: 5px;
         border: 1px solid #999;
         font-family: 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
         width:204px;
         padding:3px;
         border-spacing:3px;
         margin-left:0px;
         margin-right:auto;
    }
        select:focus {
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
            border: 1px solid #5AB0DB;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-family:inherit;
        }

        select:hover {
            border: 1px solid #999;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
            font-family:inherit;
        }

        select:focus:hover {
             outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
            border: 1px solid #5AB0DB;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-family:inherit;
        }

    textarea {
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-top-right-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI','Lucida Grande',Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
        width: 200px;
        height:45px;
        border-spacing:3px;
        margin-left:0px;
         margin-right:auto;
    }

        textarea:focus {
            outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
            border: 1px solid #5AB0DB;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-family:inherit;
        }

        textarea:hover {
            border: 1px solid #999;
            border-radius: 5px;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
            font-family:inherit;
        }

        textarea:focus:hover {
             outline: none;
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #61C5FA;
            border: 1px solid #5AB0DB;
            border-radius: 5px;
            font-family:inherit;
        }

    table {
        border-spacing:2.5px;
        column-width:auto;
        margin:auto;    
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

html code

```
<body class="body">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="Container">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <div id="ux-header" class="Chrome ltr">
            <div class="BrandLogo">
            <a href="http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us">
                <span class="BrandLogoImage msdn" title="MSDN"></span>
            </a>
            </div>
            <div class="GlobalBar">

            </div>
            <div class="internav">            


            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="body">        
            <div id="leftNav" class="leftNavResize1">
                <div class="topic" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <h1 class="title">Pest Master</h1>                   
                </div> 
                <div id="form">
                    <table style="width:auto;float:left">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width:25%">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Pest Classification"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td style="width:45%">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ComboBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>                            
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Pest Name"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:ComboBox ID="ComboBox2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="172px"></asp:ComboBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ForeColor="" Text="Measurement Unit"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="Pest Description"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text="Pest Function"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>    
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="Function Description"></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>                                
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                <%--         <tr>
                            <td >

                            </td>
                            <td>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
           <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/cl.png" AlternateText="abc" Width="150px" Height="40px" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="175px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>--%>
                    </table>
                    <div style="width:22%;float:left;margin-top:5px;margin-left:70px">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="pivot-switch" Text="Save" ValidationGroup="validate" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="width:22%;float:left;margin-top:5px;margin-left:0px">
                        <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" CssClass="pivot-switch" Text="Delete" OnClick="Button4_Click" />
                    </div>
                </div>               
                <div id="Content2" class="rightImage">
                         <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl="~/Images/pest2.jpg" Width="160px" runat="server" />
                    </div>               
            </div>        
            <div id="content" class="content">    
                <div>
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="mGrid" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sno" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <%# ((GridViewRow)Container).RowIndex +1 %>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pest Classification">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PestClassification") %>'></asp:Label>                                    
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Pest Name">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PestName") %>'></asp:Label>                                   
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PID") %>'></asp:Label>                                   
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                             <asp:TemplateField  Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("FunctionDescription") %>'></asp:Label>                                   
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                             <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("MeasurementUnit") %>'></asp:Label>                                   
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField> 
                             <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("CID") %>'></asp:Label>                                   
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>        
                             <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("GroupID") %>'></asp:Label>                                   
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>  
                               <asp:TemplateField Visible="false">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label16" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("PestDescription") %>'></asp:Label>                                   
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>                  
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>   
                 </div>                                                                             
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
         <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server"  
                PopupControlID="Panel2" TargetControlID="HiddenField1"
                CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">
            record successfully updated<br />            
            <asp:Button ID="btnClose" runat="server" Text="Close" />            
        </asp:Panel>
        <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->

         <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->

         <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender2" runat="server"  
                PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="Button3"
                CancelControlID="btnClose" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></asp:ModalPopupExtender>
         <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopup" align="center" style = "display:none">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="abc"></asp:Label></td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Save" /></td>
                    <td><asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Close" />  </td>
                </tr>
            </table>            

        </asp:Panel>
        <!-- ModalPopupExtender -->

        <!--confirmbuttonextender-->
        <asp:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="ConfirmButtonExtender1" TargetControlID="Button4" ConfirmText="do u want to delete" runat="server"></asp:ConfirmButtonExtender>
        <!--confirmbuttonextender-->


        <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server">
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="ComboBox1" SetFocusOnError="true" InitialValue="0" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Select One Option"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender1" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="ComboBox2" SetFocusOnError="true" InitialValue="-1" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Select One Option or enter pest name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender2" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="enter measurement unit"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender3" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="enter pest description"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender4" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" SetFocusOnError="true" InitialValue="0" Display="None" ErrorMessage="Select One Option"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender5" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validate" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" SetFocusOnError="true" Display="None" ErrorMessage="enter functional description"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender6" TargetControlID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validate" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.]*$" Display="None" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="ComboBox2" ErrorMessage="invalid input"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender10" TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator4" runat="server"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validate" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.]*$" Display="None" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="invalid input"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender7" TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validate" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.]*$" Display="None" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" ErrorMessage="invalid input"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender8" TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator2" runat="server"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server" ValidationGroup="validate" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.]*$" Display="None" SetFocusOnError="true" ControlToValidate="TextBox3" ErrorMessage="invalid input"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
            <asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender ID="ValidatorCalloutExtender9" TargetControlID="RegularExpressionValidator3" runat="server"></asp:ValidatorCalloutExtender>
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

please suggest something.

Comment: give only that part which is showing difficulty.. it is hard to read all the code and then tell u solution also we don't know what is the id/class of the div or textbox you have used..

Comment: HTML code ? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: i have added html code. plz try to suggest

Comment: my problem get solved by removing "position: relative; " from   #Container.